# Applescript and Automator - Safari gets stuck and I have to push Esc to continue

Tags: safari, applescript, automator

This simple Applescript works as expected:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set theURL to URL of front document
end tell
```

I now try to make an Automator action/service of it:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events"
        if (name of the first process whose frontmost is "true") is "Safari" then
            set theURL to URL of front document
        end if
    end tell
    return theURL
end run
```

but that returns an error message:

*The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “System Events got an error: Can’t get URL of document 1.”*

Hmm, so I add a `tell application "Safari" to activate` in Automator to make sure it really is Safari who receives these commands:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events"
        if (name of the first process whose frontmost is "true") is "Safari" then
            tell application "Safari"
                activate
                set theURL to URL of front document
            end tell
        end if
    end tell
    return theURL
end run
```

Weird, now the Automator action gets stuck on 0 % (as seen in the Automator cog wheel in the menu bar). To make the script finish I have to push `Esc`.

In fact, if I switch out of Safari when stuck at 0 % Safari remains backgrounded when I try to switch back to it until I press Esc. After pressing Esc Safari automatically is foregrounded and the Automator action finishes.

That is:

1. Select some text in Safari and select this service from the contextual menu.
2. Service gets stuck at 0 %.
3. Switch to another application A. This works as expected. Service is still stuck at 0 %.
4. Try to switch back to Safari using cmd-tab, dock or something else. Nothing happens, A is still in the foreground and the service is stuck at 0 %.
5. Press Esc. Now the service finishes and Safari becomes foregrounded.

Finally, I have set the Automator action to replace

So, why can't I access the URL in the first version? And why does it get stuck in the second version? How should I write this to accomplish what I want?

Edit: to clarify what I am trying to achieve. I want to get the URL from the frontmost window in Safari, process the URL and then use it somewhere else. I have removed the processing and "somewhere else" part of my Automator workflow to simplify the question.

Comment: Having read the comments, is your intended user flow something like: **1.** The user uses either _Safari_ or _Chrome_, then they select e.g. `Safari` > `Services` > `<NameOfService>` from the Menu Bar. **2.** Your script retrieves the URL and assigns it to `theURL` variable. **3.** Your script also ascertains which browser the URL came from (either _Safari_ or _Chrome_) so you can perform different logic? **4.** However if the user is using another app (not _Safari_ or _Chrome_) and selects `Safari` > `Services` > `<NameOfService>` from the Menu Bar, then your script should do nothing?

Comment: @RobC Yes, the purpose is to insert part of the URL somewhere else. However, Chrome and Safari's AS dictionaries are slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because you are running Safari terminology in a `System Events` tell block which cannot work.

Actually it's not necessary to make Safari frontmost. This line should do the job.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Safari" to return URL of front document
end run
```

A more robust version checks if the front document exists

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Safari"
        if exists document 1 then return URL of front document
        return missing value
    end tell
end run
```

If you are going to make a Automator service set `Service receives` to *no input*

Comment: It still gets stuck when I use your first version. Here is a screenshot of the whole Automator action: https://imgur.com/a/92zdIbb . Also, how do I insert the return value from your one liner into a variable? Thank :-)

Comment: What's the purpose of that weird System Events block which I guess is the bottleneck? Safari is not required to be frontmost. The AppleScript action returns the URL to pass it to the next action.

Comment: I am gonna run this service from Chrome and Safari and need to know which program it is run from. If I add logging, the tell system event-block finishes as expected and I get into the following if-clause without problem.

Comment: Every (scriptable) application has a `frontmost` property. You can simply check `if frontmost of application "Safari" then ...`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ePt2CC9 - it still gets stuck. And do you know how to store the URL Safari returns in a variable?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Automator. I'm able to write my scripts GUI-less 

Comment: I can add that I just tried the same thing with Chrome and the result was the same, Chrome gets stuck and does not return the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following to ascertain the URL and which app/browser the URL came from.

The code in the following gist is intentionally verbose for ease of understanding, and besides I don't know exactly what you want to achieve. However it acts to provide you with the general gist to achieve what you're wanting to do.

It does the following:

1. Gets the name of the frontmost application.
2. When the frontmost app is either *Safari* or *Google Chrome* it will firstly check that a window is available.

   - If a window *is not* available it will notify the user.
   - If a window *is* available it will display a dialog indicating the URL and the name of Browser it came from. This is just to demonstrate that the variables `theURL` and `whichBrowser` hold the info that you need.
3. If the Service *is not* run from either *Safari* or *Google Chrome* it will notify the user that it must be run from either *Safari* or *Google Chrome*.

---

```
on run {input, parameters}

  tell application "System Events" to set theActiveApp to name of first process where it is frontmost

  set theURL to "unknown"
  set whichBrowser to "unknown"

  if theActiveApp is equal to "Safari" then
    tell application "Safari"
      if exists document 1 then
        set theURL to URL of current tab of window 1
        set whichBrowser to theActiveApp
      else
        display dialog "This service requires active window in Safari with a URL" & return & return & "Try opening a new window." with icon caution
        return
      end if
    end tell
  else if theActiveApp is equal to "Google Chrome" then
    tell application "Google Chrome"
      if exists window 1 then
        set theURL to URL of active tab of window 1
        set whichBrowser to theActiveApp
      else
        display dialog "This service requires active window in Chrome with a URL" & return & return & "Try opening a new window." with icon caution
        return
      end if
    end tell
  end if

  -- The Service was NOT run from either Safari or Google Chrome
  if theURL = "unknown" and whichBrowser = "unknown" then
    tell application "Finder"
      activate
      display dialog "This Service must be run from either Safari or Google Chrome" & theActiveApp with icon caution
    end tell
  else
    -- Report the results
    display dialog "The url is: " & theURL & return & return & "From app: " & theActiveApp
  end if

  -- ONLY return theURL to the next task if we've got it.
  if theURL ≠ "unknown" then
      return theURL
  end if

end run
```

**Note**

In the last part that reads:

```
if theURL ≠ "unknown" then
    return theURL
end if
```

This will cause the Workflow to stop running if `theURL` is not known (i.e. The service was not run from either *Safari/Chrome* or a window was not open in the browser). Otherwise it will pass `theURL` to the next Automator task.

---

**Version of the script with only the necessary dialogs**

This version below will only display the necessary dialogs and does not report *theURL* and `whichBrowser` variables in a dialog.

```
on run {input, parameters}

  tell application "System Events" to set theActiveApp to name of first process where it is frontmost

  set theURL to missing value

  if theActiveApp is equal to "Safari" then
    tell application "Safari"
      if exists document 1 then
        set theURL to URL of current tab of window 1
      else
        display dialog "This service requires active window in Safari with a URL" & return & return & "Try opening a new window." with icon caution
        return -- return early
      end if
    end tell
  else if theActiveApp is equal to "Google Chrome" then
    tell application "Google Chrome"
      if exists window 1 then
        set theURL to URL of active tab of window 1
      else
        display dialog "This service requires active window in Chrome with a URL" & return & return & "Try opening a new window." with icon caution
        return -- return early
      end if
    end tell
  end if

  if theURL is equal to missing value then
    -- The Service was NOT run from either Safari or Google Chrome
    tell application "Finder"
      activate
      display dialog "This Service must be run from either Safari or Google Chrome" & theActiveApp with icon caution
    end tell
  else
    -- ONLY return theURL to the next Automator task if we've got it.
    return theURL
  end if

end run
```